# heap size while scrolling in listView

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-listview, heap-memory, heap-dump

In list-view while scrolling through List-view heap-size is continuously increasing, it reaches to 64MB on Galaxy S3 device and application gets crashed.

```
public class GAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<G> list;
private GActivity mContext;
private Drawable attach , text;
private HttpImageManager mHttpImageManager;
private LayoutInflater mInfalotar;

public GAdapter(GActivity context , List<G> list){

    this.list = list;
    mContext = context;
    mInfalotar = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 


    mHttpImageManager = ((GApplication)context.getApplication()).getHttpImageManager();

    attach = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_attachment);
    text   = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_text);
}

public void addContact(VamooseGroup entry){
    list.add(entry);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setGroupList(List<G> g){
    list.clear();
    datavalues = null;
    list.addAll(g);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return (list.size()+1);
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int index) {

    if(index != list.size())
        return list.get(index);
    else
        return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int index) {
    return index;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return list.size()+1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position == list.size() ? 1 : 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int index, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        int type = getItemViewType(index);

        switch(type){

            case 0 :

            convertview = mInfalotar.inflate(R.layout.data_listitem , viewGroup, false);

            ImageView myimageView =  (ImageView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
            TextView groupname    =  (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.groupname);
            TextView timespam     =  (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.timeInfo);
            TextView msgSender    =  (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.msgowner);
            TextView draft        =  (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.draft);
            ImageView watchIcon   =  (ImageView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.time);
            ImageView attachment  =  (ImageView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.attachment);

            final G g = list.get(index);
            String grouppic = g.pic();
            if(ImageValidator.validate(grouppic)){
                  Bitmap bitmap = mHttpImageManager.loadImage(new HttpImageManager.LoadRequest(Uri.parse(grouppic), myimageView));
                  if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                        myimageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                  }
            }

            parent.setBackgroundDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.select));
            groupname.setText("FOO1");
            msgbox.setText("FOO2");
            groupname.setText("F003");
            msgSender.setText("F004");  
            timespam.setText("F005");
            attachment.setBackgroundDrawable(attach);
            watchIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(text);


        break;

        }

    return convertview;
}
```

}

above code is List-adapter used. i'm using the the following library for showing the images
[android-http-image-manager](http://code.google.com/p/android-http-image-manager/)

can someone tell me why bitmaps are not getting recycled? heap is continuously increasing while scrolling list-view and reaches to 64MB.please provide a brief solution.

Comment: Can you also post the logcat? My first guess is that you are not recycling the convertview but inflating the xml all the time. That could cause the outofmemory error.

Comment: Might be bcoz you haven't followed view holder approach and everything is kept in memory.

Comment: @Andro Selva i have tried useing Viewholder approach but all of my view are of different kind , also if i'm creating a listItem at runtime for listview then how should i apply ViewHolder approcah.

Answer (score 1):

A ListView is smart and there are many ways to recycle your views to increase the performance. One of these is to implement the [ViewHolder-pattern](http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166).

But this will not solve your problem. The problem you are facing is that you have overriden the `getViewTypeCount()` method and returning a huge number. The `ListView` won't recycle any view because for each row, you have a different type.

You can solve your problem by not overriding this method, or returning the number of different row types. This means.. If you have 2 different layouts available for your list. You return 2.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: @Martin Van Mierloo please suggest a way how should i use viewHolder approach if all the views are of different kind, e.g. in the above example if use it like if(condition)   attachment.setBackgroundDrawable(attach);
 else attachment.setBackgroundDrawable(null); in this case ViewHolder doesn't provide correct results.

Comment: The best tutorial I found is [logc.at](http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/). It's a nice and clean implementation of a `ListView` with different rows.

Comment: @Martijin Van Mierloo i'm reading it,is there any way to deal with bitmaps they are also not seemed to recycled and continuously taking memory the above library "android-http-image-manager" doesn't use WeakRefrence approach.